# How to Print Array of Objects to Screen?

Tags: java, oop

I want to print each date object in the array of dates (myDates) to the screen.
The date class has values of month, day and year.

```
private static void printDates(Date[] myDates) throws IOException {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    if(myDates.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("There are no dates to print.\n");
}
    else {
        System.out.println("Print the dates to the screen or to a file?");
        System.out.println("  1. Print to screen.");
        System.out.println("  2. Print to a new file.");
        System.out.print("Choice: ");
        int option = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        if(option == 1) {
            for(int i = 0; i < myDates.length; i++) { //Is this necessary?
                //Don't know how to print array of objects with toString method in date class.
            }
```

I'm thinking it has to do with the get and set methods of the date class, but not too sure how to correctly do those.

```
public String getDate() {
    return "" + month.getMonth() + " " + day.getDay() + " " + year.getYear();
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    //maybe make a date string then this.date = date; ???
}
```

Or maybe you would use the date class' toString method? This might not be correct.

```
public String toString(e) {
    return getMonthWord(day.toString()) + " " + month.toString() + " " + year.getYear();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to print each date object in the array of dates (myDates) to
>   the screen.

Firstly, for a `toString()` method, you need not pass in a parameter, as you've stated the `toString()` method you've created is indeed incorrect.

change this:

```
public String toString(e) {
    return getMonthWord(day.toString()) + " " + month.toString() + " " + year.getYear();
}
```

to this:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.day + " / " + this.month + " / " + this.year;
}
```

considering each date in the array has a `toString()`, you can simply do this:

```
if(option == 1) {
    Arrays.stream(myDates).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

or using typical foreach loop:

```
if(option == 1) {
     for(Date d : myDates) System.out.println(d);
}
```

Basically, what happens is whenever the `System.out.println` invokes any `Date` object within the array, then the `toString()` method is invoked automatically for that particular `Date` object, you need not say `d.toString()`